# Vector print out wrong value

Tags: c++, vector

Hi I got a question about the following code. I will copy a char string, which i read out of a file into a vector and print out this vector on the screen. the program copy the string out ouf the textfile but the vector only gives out the last element of the vector. what did i wrong here?? :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "mbusread.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int dev_nr;
    int anzahl;
    ifstream addr;
    string buffer;
    string dev_no;
    stringstream devss;
    char *reg_no_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
    char *start_reg_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
    char *adresse_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
    char *id_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
    char *zeit_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];

    addr.open("Addr.xml", ios::in); //Addressendatei auslesen
    do //Anzahl suchen
    {
        getline(addr, buffer);
    }   while(strcmp (buffer.c_str(), "<Anzahl>")!=0);
        getline(addr, buffer);

        stringstream bufferss(buffer);
        bufferss >> anzahl;
        anzahl++;

        vector<const char *> ip(anzahl);
        vector<const char *> start_reg(anzahl);
        vector<const char *> reg_no(anzahl);
        vector<const char *> id(anzahl);
        vector<const char *> zeit(anzahl);


    for(dev_nr=1;dev_nr<anzahl;dev_nr++)
    {
        addr.seekg(ios::beg);
        devss << "<dev" << dev_nr << ">";
        dev_no = devss.str();
        devss.str("");
        devss.clear();

        do {
            getline(addr, buffer);
            if(addr.eof())
            {
             break;
            }
          } while (strcmp (buffer.c_str(),dev_no.c_str()) != 0);

        do // ip suchen
        {
            getline(addr, buffer);
        }while(strcmp (buffer.c_str(), "<ip>")!=0);
        getline(addr, buffer);
        if(addr.eof())
        {
         break;
        }
        strcpy(adresse_c, buffer.c_str()); // ip einlesen
        ip[dev_nr - 1] = adresse_c;
        cout << ip[dev_nr - 1] << endl;

        do // start_reg suchen
        {
            getline(addr, buffer);
        }while(strcmp(buffer.c_str(), "<start_reg>")!=0);
        if(addr.eof())
        {
         break;
        }
        getline(addr, buffer);              //Schreibt Startregister in Daten
        strcpy(start_reg_c, buffer.c_str()); // ip einlesen
        start_reg[dev_nr - 1] = start_reg_c;
        cout << start_reg[dev_nr - 1] << endl;

        do // reg_no suchen
        {
            getline(addr, buffer);
        }while(strcmp(buffer.c_str(), "<reg_no>")!=0);
        if(addr.eof())
        {
         break;
        }
        getline(addr, buffer);              //Schreibt die Anzahl der ausgelesenen Register in Daten
        strcpy(reg_no_c, buffer.c_str()); // ip einlesen
        reg_no[dev_nr - 1] = reg_no_c;
        cout << reg_no[dev_nr - 1] << endl;

        do // ID suchen
        {
            getline(addr, buffer);
        }while(strcmp(buffer.c_str(), "<ID>")!=0);
        if(addr.eof())
        {
         break;
        }
        getline(addr, buffer);              //Schreibt die ID des Sensors in Daten
        strcpy(id_c, buffer.c_str()); // ip einlesen
        id[dev_nr - 1] = id_c;
        cout << id[dev_nr - 1] << endl;

        do
        {
            getline(addr, buffer);
        }while(strcmp(buffer.c_str(), "<Time>")!=0);
        if(addr.eof())
        {
            break;
        }
        getline(addr, buffer);
        strcpy(zeit_c, buffer.c_str()); // ip einlesen
        zeit[dev_nr - 1] = zeit_c;
        cout << zeit[dev_nr - 1] << endl;

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++)
    {
        cout << "ip " << ip[i] << endl;
        cout << "id " << id[i] << endl;
        cout << "start_reg " << start_reg[i] << endl;
        cout << "reg_no " << reg_no[i] << endl;
        cout << "zeit " << zeit[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you reduce the code to the essence of the problem?

Comment: Also provide some input xml file, please.

Comment: Debug it. Find out where it starts to go wrong. Then post only that relevant code.

Comment: here is a hint - try to understand what `const char*` really means - then look at how you are using it, it will become very clear...

Comment: Let's not mix german and english code. English only is the way to go. (and that comment comes from a German.)

Comment: Why this ugly mix of C and C++? there is std::string, just use it.

Comment: Sorry for this but I’m a beginner in programming. I had it for a semester in the university and have to use it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem starts right at the top of the code

```
string buffer;
string dev_no;
stringstream devss;
char *reg_no_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
char *start_reg_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
char *adresse_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
char *id_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
char *zeit_c = new char [buffer.length()+1];
```

A this point `buffer` is empty, so `length()` returns 0 and you allocate just a single byte for the C strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but my opinion is that you should really learn how to read a xml file. Your code is so convoluted, although what it really does is simply try to "hack an parse" a xml file, that many people will feel like it is not worth trying to correct it.

- Xerces is  the most famous C++ XML Api, though is is a huge library.
  See a sample with xerces DOM reading here : http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-dom-2.html
- If xerces is a too big library, why not try TinyXML : see a sample here : http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html